# Android Realm get Not inside a transaction Error

Tags: java, android

## Problem Resolved

problem resolved by replace `realm.commitTransaction();` with `realm.copyToRealm(item);`

## Problem

When i get data from dialog by listener as `interface` and try to save chosen data as class model. i can not create new row in table

Get data from dialog:

```
takeUserEwalletCurrency.setOnTakeUserEwallet(new TakeUserEwalletCurrency.IOnChooseEwallet() {
    @Override
    public void getItem(int item) {
        takeUserEwalletCurrency.dismissDialog();
        switch (item) {
            case 1:
                String choiceUSDUserEwallet = "SHUSD" + userPhoneNumber.substring(1, userPhoneNumber.length());
                updateEwalletsHistory(choiceUSDUserEwallet, "SHUSD");
                to_ewallet.setText(choiceUSDUserEwallet);
                validateEnteredEwalletNumber();
                break;
            case 2:
                ...
                break;
        }
    }
});
takeUserEwalletCurrency.showDialog();
```

Create a new row:

```
private void updateEwalletsHistory(final String currentEwallet, final String ewalletCurrency) {
    final EwalletsHistory exists_row = realm.where(EwalletsHistory.class).equalTo("ewalletName", currentEwallet).findFirst();

    if (exists_row == null) {
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                EwalletsHistory item = new EwalletsHistory();
                item.setEwalletName(currentEwallet);
                item.setEwalletCurrency(ewalletCurrency);
                realm.commitTransaction();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

both of them such as Dialog interface and create new row in table are the same activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling `commitTransaction()` inside `executeTransaction()`.

`executeTransaction()` handles `begin/commit/cancelTransaction()` method calls.